# Demarcated "Proof Idea"

Tags: textbooks, proofs, reference-books

Michael Sipser's textbook *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* (now 3rd ed.) includes for each major theorem, a demarcated **Proof Idea** of length a paragraph to more than a page, prior to presenting the formal **Proof**.

I am seeking examples of textbooks that do something similar, regularly providing
proof sketches prior to the proofs. Of course it is not uncommon to sketch the main idea
before a proof, but I am seeking systematic use of this pedagogical practice spanning an entire textbook.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but ["How to Read and Do Proofs: An Introduction to Mathematical Thought Processes" by Solow](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118164024) is an intro-to-proof-writing book that frequently goes very slow and wordily through a proof/argument before giving the concise mathematical version.

Comment: Great example---Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two great books that do this are the books on [proof writing](https://longformmath.com/proofs-home) and [real analysis](https://longformmath.com/analysis-home) by Jay Cummings.